# Как организовать БД

Tags: база-данных, хранение-данных

Планируется создать сайт. Бд на mysql. На сайте люди регистрируются и создают свой аккаунт (не ограниченное количество аккаунтов, может 1000). Потом посетитель сайта, любой человек из сети без регистрации по капче может голосовать за любого аккаунта. При голосовании вводит объяснение (текстовое поле размером text).
Голосов на одного аккаунта может быть не ограниченное количество.

Интересует, как хранить такую информацию?

Хранить все голоса в одной таблице с дополнительной колонкой `parent_id`, которая будет указывать на аккаунт или для каждого аккаунта создавать отдельную таблицу?

Comment: в одной таблице

Comment: Данные одного типа (почти) всегда нужно хранить в одной таблице

Answer (score 1):

Как в комментах писали, конечно нужно хранить все голоса в одной таблице с привязкой к юзеру за кого голосуют. Получается таблица из трех столбцов: `id`, `vote_for_id`, `comment` как пример. `vote_for_id` у тебя получается `id` пользователя за кого проголосовали.

Comment: А не лучше ли кол-во голосов добавить в таблицу юзеров?

Comment: Тут даже два столбца лучше, чёт затупил, поле id ненужно по сути. На счёт добавления голосов в таблицу юзеров не лучше, это получается нужно апдейтить поле, и если учесть, что это голосовалка, могут быть проблемы с блокировкой и т.п.